# .NET SMTP.send not working but no errors

Tags: .net, email, smtp, send

I have a fully functional VB.NET solution working with a simple standard code i found in a lot of websites around the net, that is something like this:

```
    Dim oMessage As New MailMessage
    oMessage.From = New MailAddress("someone@abc.com")
    oMessage.To.Add("someone_else@abc.com")
    oMessage.Subject = "test mail"
    oMessage.Body = "test mail body"
    oMessage.IsBodyHtml = False
    Dim oSMTP As New SmtpClient("192.168.1.253")
    oSMTP.Port = 25
    oSMTP.EnableSsl = False
    oSMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("someone@abc.com", "password")
    oSMTP.Send(oMessage)
```

The working solution relies on the gmail smtp server with the usual configuration.
I tried to replicate the same solution in another environment, where the smtp server is in the company LAN (192.168.1.253) and uses port 25, no SSL is required.
The facts:
1) the server I am trying to deploy my solution on is running a third-party software sending email from a dedicated address (I need to use the same email address). This functionality is active and working;
2) I tried to connect to the SMPT server via telnet and I succeeded in sending an email to my private email address through SMPT protocol. This was expected, because the other software encounters no problem in doing the same job;
3) I tested my solution, with try-catch block to get any error, but no email reaches the destination, even if my code terminates with no errors.

I tried a lot of different options for smtp and message (and also with alternative destination addresses), but the result has always been the same: no message is sent. The last chance I have is to look for any conflict with server configuration or antivirus software. But I cannot realize why a "plain" dialog with the server through SMPT protocol is successful and my very simple code is not.

Last note: the mail server i mentioned should be a Microsoft Exchange Server.

Where could be the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably the solution was the only combination I forgot in my hundred tests... As soon as i added the line oSMTP.dispose, the solution began to work. This suggestion is found in a couple of other threads, I probably missed it or maybe I tried it with a wrong configuration, so an error was reported before the end of the code was reached.

Comment: Just to emphatize the actual solution: ALWAYS USE THE DISPOSE METHOD AFTER USING THE SMTPClient Object to be sure that the connection with the server is closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use wireshark to monitor communications between your application and your mail server; I know i once had a similar problem and I was able to see the error message the server responded with after receiving the message(for some reason the error message wasn't making it all the way up to the application)

Also do this:

```
                oMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
```

So if the server fails to send your message, you will be notified.

Also, if you use the SendAsync method to send your mail, and you bind yourself to the SendCompleted Event(of your smtp object), you should be able to see any errors in the AsyncCompletedEventArgs object the event will give you.

Comment: Thank you. This was one of my options but I was not aware of what application to use to monitor the communication to/from the server. Probabily this would have helped me in finding the solution.